# Closed graph implies function is lower semi continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Recall that a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is called lower semi continuous if $f^{-1}(-\infty, a]$ is closed for every $a \in \mathbb {R}$

> Suppose graph of a function $f$ is closed then is it true that $f$ is lower semi continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Consider

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & \text{for } x < 0 \\ x & \text{for } x \geqslant 0 \end{cases}$$

[image]

- The graph of $f$ is closed;
- $f^{-1} \big[ (-\infty, -1] \big] = [-1, 0)$ is not closed.

**Explanation of the idea**: a function is lower semi-continuous if it never jumps up, i.e.

$$f(x_0) \leqslant \liminf_{x \to x_0} f(x)$$

for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. To spoil that property we produce a jump up, say in $x_0 = 0$, so that

$$a = \liminf_{x \to 0^-} f(x) < f(0) = 0$$

and make the function continuous everywhere else. But now, if $\displaystyle c = \limsup_{x \to 0^-} f(x) > -\infty$, we could pick $b \in [a, c]$ such that $b < 0$ and by the Darboux property there would be a sequence $x_n \to 0^-$ such that $f(x_n) \to b$. This would mean that graph is not closed, since $x_n \to 0, f(x_n) \to b$ but $f(0) > b$. Hence we're forced to set $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = -\infty$.

And this is basically how this graph is built.

Comment: Thank you. The example seems good. Could you just say how did you think of this example?

Comment: just distinguish the concept of graph and preimage: the former one in your setting is set in $\mathbb R^2$: $\{(x, y): f(x)\leq y\}$

Comment: @Dontknowanything Added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Adayah: Thank you very much!